# Can Mathematica convert PDF into QR code too?

Tags: graphics, image-processing

I recently learned that we can embed a whole PDF file into QR codes.
But many online sites are not free for this service.

Just wondering if Mathematica can do this?
Note I don't want to convert the file into images, then into QR.
I would like to preserve the `PDF` format in the QR code when it's `scanned`.

Thanks.

Comment: PDFs generally seem to be too large to be encoded as QR codes. I encoded a two page PDF in the base64 format, and the resulting string is 291,144 characters long. Meanwhile, the documentation for `BarcodeImage` suggests that the limit for a QR code is 2953 ASCII characters. So, I'm not really seeing how this could work. Perhaps the websites use a generalized form of QR codes? Perhaps they extract the text and encode only that? Could you give a link to one of these websites?

Comment: Are you sure they encode the whole PDF? Not just a *url* to the PDF online?

Comment: Hmmmm now if I Tobi know about it, it could be just a url link to the PDF... I will test more and update you here.

Comment: https://www.qr-code-generator.com/solutions/pdf-qr-code/ This is the one I used. But it looks like only thing embedded was a url link.